# Margin for a paper

Tags: margins

I am trying to send a paper to a conference with specific margin requirements. I use the geometry package to define the margins.

```
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in, top=0.75in]{geometry}
```

However, I still get errors when trying to upload. e.g, right margin of page 6 is 0.958 inches, which does not leave 1 inches of margin.

Why are the margins set by geometry getting overridden? Is there a way to hard set the margins if so?

Comment: Someone suggested to use "includeall". i dont even know is that a package or a command, how to use it? Googled it, no luck

Comment: If that problem is only for that page, there may be a table or a floating element, which sometimes goes beyond the limits, or for the type of document, please elaborate an example of minimum latex code that is compilable and that contains that error To be able to help you.

Comment: I tired deleting all the figures, submitted the paper only with texts, still the same problem showing. Tried deleting page 6, now the problem shows in page 2. So, i do not think it is a problem with just one page. :(

Comment: Give us the code to do something ...

Comment: \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in, top=0.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\begin{document}
...
...
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{Cite}
\end{document}

Comment: \usepackage[letterpaper, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in, top=0.75in]{geometry}

this is suggested from the conference webpage.

Comment: Do you use pdflatex?

Comment: Yes, i use pdflatex

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce the error; there are an MWE so you can tell me what to add to generate that error.

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% arara: bibtex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}

\documentclass[conference,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in, top=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding for interpreter
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Allows the definition of hex colors
\usepackage{colortbl} % colors library.
\definecolor{klein}{HTML}{002fa7} % Klein blue
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=True,citecolor=red,urlcolor=klein]{hyperref}% For Hyperlinks

\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
%\usepackage{natbib} %Is not compatible with IEEEtran %Try using plainnat
% Enables to cite using author names  commands \citet \citep
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{IEEEtran Conference Mode}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Foo Bar}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{School of Electrical and\\
        Computer Engineering\\
        Foo Institute of Technology\\
        Foo, Bar 454545--4545\\
        Email: foo@bar.edu}
    \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Homer Simpson}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\
        Springfield, USA\\
        Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
    \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Foo Bar\\
        and Bar Foo}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{Foo Academy\\
        San Francisco, California 45454-4545\\
        Telephone: (800) 454--4545\\
        Fax: (888) 454--4545}}
    \IEEEspecialpapernotice{(Testing Paper)}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
            \lipsum[1]
    \end{abstract}

    \begin{IEEEkeywords}
            Broad band networks, quality of service, WDM.
    \end{IEEEkeywords}
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}
    \IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}}
    \IEEEPARstart{S}{ome} author \cite{cultLIBRE}, another author or reference\cite{cisco}. some text that is used to complete\footnote{\lipsum[5]} a line.\\
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \noindent\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Some Example}
        \label{example1}
    \end{figure}
    \vspace{3\baselineskip}
    \IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{MORE TEXT}\label{sec:MORETEXT}}
    \lipsum[3-4]
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \noindent\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Some Example}
        \label{example2}
    \end{figure}

    \lipsum[6-8]
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

    \bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Actual result:

[image]